# Por que resultou removendo a palavra "fu.king" numa edição rejeitada?

Tags: debate, edição

ontem reparei por acaso numa pergunta que tinha a palavra "f...ing" no seu conteúdo. Editei removendo a palavra (um palavrão em Inglês) e já agora juntei alguns acentos. Deixei o seguinte comentário:

> Comentário: removi a palavra F e corrigi alguns erros de ortografia:

Agora, como a edição foi rejeitada, estou com uma duvida: podemos usar no SO.pt esta palavra, ou foi rejeitando a edição um error?

Aqui a edição em questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/203311

Comment: Eu rejeitei a edição porque, como já disseram, achei irrelevante as alterações. Em relação ao palavrão em inglês, confesso que parei alguns instantes pra pensar a respeito, mas cheguei à conclusão que não achei tão agressiva a palavra (apenas uma) ainda mais por ser em inglês. Apesar de ser uma palavra de baixo calão em inglês, visualmente para nós falantes do português não parece muuuuito agressiva visualmente (minha opinião). Achei que ela ali sozinha não estava fazendo mt mal e a sua retirada não ia melhorar a pergunta, por isso rejeitei a edição.

Comment: @Sam Eu entretanto acho que nenhum dos sites da plataforma Stackexchange devia conter palavrões - seja de que lingua foram- nas perguntas ou respostas. Simplesmente por uma razão: isto é (ou vai ser um dia talvêz) o melhor repositório de conheçimento mundial, onde palavrões não deviam fazer parte (excepto em sites linguísticos, discutindo os mesmos)

Comment: Concordo com vc, acho feio usar esses termos, mesmo sendo em inglês. Acho que nenhum autor de pergunta/resposta deveria usar palavras desse tipo, MAS, como eu havia dito, só não achei que a remoção da tal palavra fosse motivo para aprovação da edição. Em relação às correções de ortografia, eu arrisco dizer que sou o maior defensor disso, de se escrever um português sem erros ortográficos, mas em casos de aprovação de edição, eu só voto a favor caso os erros comprometam substancialmente o entendimento da pergunta.

Comment: Será que isso influencia nos buscadores? Há a possibilidade de filtrar páginas com palavras de baixo calão...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Aprovei sua edição.

O que provavelmente ocorre é que num primeiro momento, parece uma edição supérflua, que não altera nada importante, talvez os usuários em questão na fila nem tenham notado a tal palavra (ou não acharam que justificava o edit). De fato, somente eles podem dizer o que pensaram a respeito.

O que claramente não é tolerado aqui, é ofensa pessoal, o que aparentemente não houve no caso em questão. Creio que provavelmente estas situações teriam que ser vistas caso a caso mesmo, pois dependem muito da percepção de cada um.

Um bom ponto de partida sobre o que de fato não é tolerado, é o [Código de conduta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: [Enquanto isso, na Flórida...](https://www.google.com/maps/@30.1815813,-82.6390565,3a,54.8y,224.23h,90.37t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sH73AqRGQuEkkjm1t-GY8-A!2e0!7i13312!8i6656)

Comment: muito bom este o seu link :) aqui há outro que explica (em Inglês) como usar a cuja palavra apropriadamente: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Nx0sQLl7IY

Answer (score 7):

Provavelmente foi rejeitado por causa da pouca relevância da edição. Ela até melhorou um pouco a postagem, mas não resolve tudo o que tem de problema nela. A pergunta é ruim, e a edição não a faz se tornar sustentável. Como você ainda ganha pontos pelas edições alguma pessoas consideram que está fazendo isto só pelos pontos. Não posso afirmar, mas provavelmente foi por isso que rejeitaram e nada tem a ver com o palavrão, que não é legal, principalmente neste caso que não acrescenta nada ao texto, a pessoa só quis fazer graça e poderia ser uma palavra melhor (nenhuma era melhor ainda), mas pode ser postado. Note que ela ainda não havia sido rejeitada em definitivo, apenas tinha votos para isto, mas no fim foi aprovada.

Comment: removendo um palavrão acho é significativo, mesmo sendo um palavrão em Inglês, provavelmente o palavrão mais usado do mundo, Eu não quero saber de pontos, porque não estou ativo em SO.pt. A edição foi rejeitada por 2 utilizadores, mas o seu colega moderador aprovou a edição

Comment: Apesar do termo, tambem achei a ediçao irrelevante, rejeitaria tambem num primeiro instante